# How i can get a solution to these errors?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I got these errors. I do not know how to get rid of them. First is about arguments, but is there an argument that shall be added? And at the second, i do not know where is the error. Has anyone any solution for these ?

````
Error: src/app/Mineral/add-mineral/add-mineral.component.html:8:26 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

       ``` <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  [formGroup]="addMineralForm">```
                           ~~~~~~~~

 `` src/app/Mineral/add-mineral/add-mineral.component.ts:13:16
       templateUrl: './add-mineral.component.html',```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AddMineralComponent.
````

onSubmit function :

```
onSubmit(Form: NgForm)
  {
    this.nextClicked = true;
    if(this.allTabsValid()){
      this.mapMineral();
      this.MineralWorldService.addMineral(this.mineral);
      alertyfy.success("Congrats");
      console.log(this.addMineralForm);
    }else {

    }alertyfy.error("Try again");


  }
```

Comment: Please post the `onSubmit` function implementation.

Comment: the onSubmit function is up now

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that the `onSubmit` function here expects a parameter, but in the `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` you are not passing any parameter.

I am assuming that your `addMineralForm` form, has been created using the FormBuilder, similar to this.

```
this.addMineralForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    field1: ['', Validators.required],
    field2: [''],
    ...
})
```

where `this.formBuilder` comes from the component constructor.

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
```

I would suggest you to remove the parameter from the function implementation, and check if the form is valid and just do what you need there by accessing the `FormGroup` you've created using the `FormBuilder` in order to get values from your fields, like this:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.addMineralForm.invalid) {
        this.displayErrors = true;
        return;
    }

    // you can now access fields, and the entire form, for example:
    const formData = this.addMineralForm.getRawValue();
    // do other stuff here before passing your form values to a service
}
```

I think it would be best if you would read more in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) for the FormGroup to understand how it works.